# PHP CRC32 length output

Tags: php, hash, crc32

Is there anything that can make the returned length of the PHP CRC32 function to vary?

Thanks!

Comment: It might help to explain why you want to do that? Perhaps you're asking the wrong question?

Comment: Storing the data, i want to make sure that a CRC32 always fits in a INT field, for eg.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, by definition a CRC32 has 32-bits.

You can only vary its representation. For instance, while it can be represented with 4 8-bit bytes (and hence fits in a PHP int), you may wish to represent that number in base 10 in a string, and then it can have 10 characters (unsigned), since 2^32-1 is 4294967295.